# Gradle plugins in java

Tags: eclipse, plugins, groovy, gradle

I want to write a custom plugin for gradle and move my gradle tasks to it. Now, I am using eclipse to write groovy code for my plugin and creating a jar as an output which is being used by my gradle project. I have been comfortable with writing tasks in android studio for gradle but I am not so comfortable with groovy in eclipse. I am sure there must be a slight difference in syntax but I am not aware. If some one can help. Ex, I have this task :

```
task example(type: Copy) {
delete('dist/')
from('build/intermediates/bundles/release')
into('dist/')

include('classes.jar')

def jarName = componentName + '-' + versionName + buildNumber + '.jar'
rename('classes.jar', jarName)
}
```

How to write the task in the Plugin in eclipse.

Comment: Please do some basic research before asking questions. see here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html

Comment: I have gone through this site and many other demos that are available online. But, my question is more specific. This information is not given in the link you have shared or those that I have gone through, Please reply if you have any specific information for above problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example of creating a custom plugin that adds a task to the task graph

```
class MySweetPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.getTasks().create("mySweetTask", SomeTask)
    }
}

class SomeTask extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    void thisIsMyTask() throws Exception {
        // do task work
    }
}
```

You task being type `Copy` might look more like this, depends on what you want to do and how separated you want your code.

```
class MySweetPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.getTasks().create(type: Copy, "copyToLib") {
            delete('dist/')
            from('build/intermediates/bundles/release')
            into('dist/')
            include('classes.jar')

            def jarName = componentName + '-' + versionName + buildNumber + '.jar'
            rename('classes.jar', jarName)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, This doesn't work. I have already tried but it gives me error in Android Studio : No Such property Copy for Class: gradle.plugin

Comment: @sver, so import it. This is just a class reference. Nobody will do the job for you.

Comment: @Opal, I only need directions as I don't understand these errors

Comment: The fully qualified import of `Copy` is `org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy`  here is the API doc for the `Copy` task:  https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/Copy.html and for completeness here is the DSL doc also:  https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html

Comment: Replace the `type: Copy` (explicitly just the `Copy` word) with the fully qualified class path... If your IDE is worth its salt it will offer to simplify the fully qualified reference with an import statement

Comment: Using the fully qualified name, I get error : Could not find property org on the funcName . Certainly , it is not taking the  fully qualified name as the type also. I am working on eclipse, not sure if it supports.